# returning data from a dataframe using jsonify

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a web service and the pattern to return data is basically get the required data into a dataframe and then use the code below to return the data.

```
return jsonify([{'id': row.id,
                 'name': row.name,
                 'age': row.age
                 } for row in data.itertuples()])
```

This works fine. However as is the case now when I have a dataframe with 30 odd columns is there a more efficient way of doing this? I don't want to have copy the above and write 30 lines of 'some_name' : row.some_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over attributes of your `rows` and return ones that aren't special methods (ones that starts with `_`) or functions.

```
def get_attributes(obj):
    return {
        attr: getattr(obj, attr) for attr in dir(obj) if 
        not attr.startswith('_') and not callable(getattr(obj, attr))
    }
```

---

Example usage:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': [0, 1],
        'name': ['name_1', 'name_2'],
        'age': [16, 32]
    },
    index=['dog', 'hawk']
)

print([
    get_attributes(row)
    for row in data.itertuples()
])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Index': 'dog', 'age': 16, 'id': 0, 'name': 'name_1'},
 {'Index': 'hawk', 'age': 32, 'id': 1, 'name': 'name_2'}]
```